# How to do I delete Nx distributed cache

Tags: distributed-caching

My project is having an issue in our build systems where a command has been written to the cloud cache **NOT IN NODE_MODULES** incorrectly and is poisoning all subsequent runs. How do I clear the distributed cache?

The only thing I can think of is running with the --skip-nx-cache option, but if I don't run with the flag I get the same error again because the cache is still bad.

Answer (score 0):

i can not see an option to clear the distributed cache in their ui in free plan.

One can try this from the [docs](https://nx.dev/ci/features/remote-cache)

> passing --no-cloud will tell Nx not to use the remote cache from Nx
> Cloud

and/or in nx.json in "build" section

```
"cache": false
```

however, i did the "hard" way:

- delete local nx cache
- delete the workspace in cloud.nx.app
- reinit local nx workspace with 'npx nx connect'